# With Eloquent only extract items with a complete date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I just want to extract items that have a complete date, Unfortunately video games do not always have a precise date While others are deleted.

For this reason some of my dates, rather than being composed "2017-03-29" they have: "2017" or "Deleted"

This is my code:

```
        $giochi = InfoGiochi::with('Giochi')
            ->where('data', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth())
        ->paginate(10);
```

I try with:

```
        ->where('data', date('Y-m-d'))
```

While:

> Carbon::now()->subMonth()

I want to extract only complete dates, that is, composed "Y/m/d".
Because now it also extracts incomplete dates, such as: "2017" or "delete".

Comment: What does a `complete date` mean? Does that mean that sometimes you will have `2017` and other times `2017-06`, and other times `2017-06-09`, or do you mean sometimes it's `null`? can you clarify?

Comment: you have to be more clear what you are asking for

Comment: I want to extract only complete dates, that is, composed "Y/m/d", Because now it also extracts incomplete dates, such as: "2017" or "delete". [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Rc9UHaU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with:

```
    $giochi = InfoGiochi::with('Giochi')
        ->whereMonth('data', '=', date('m'))
        ->whereYear('data', date('Y'))
    ->get();
```